# .htaccess - How to redirect if NO specific useragent?

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hello dear Stackoverflow,

I have an issue with DoS attacks, I tried to filter the attacks with .htaccess but at the moment there is no user agent sent at all, so how can I filter this attack? I have managed to filter many of the useragents - but now Apache does not show any user agents.

I have tried to add RewriteConditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [nocase] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Requests:

```
x.x.x.x - - [21/Jun/2019:03:25:00 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3397
x.x.x.x - - [21/Jun/2019:03:24:50 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3397
x.x.x.x - - [21/Jun/2019:03:24:50 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3397
x.x.x.x - - [21/Jun/2019:03:24:48 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3397
x.x.x.x - - [21/Jun/2019:03:24:57 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3397
```

how can I filter this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure there's no user-agent? Empty referrers and user-agents usually show up as `"-"` in Apache logs, for example: `103.48.83.217 - - [16/Jun/2019:06:40:43 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5103 "-" "-"` Do you see a user-agent in the other requests?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Usually I have these lines like you have displayed - but now there are none. This is at the moment the issues that I am facing.

Comment: Are all the lines in the log without the referrer and user-agent at all? If so, you might need to adjust your logging settings.

Comment: No, only the ones from the attacks. All the other log entries are fine.